# How to throw a future through waitFor in Dart

Tags: exception, dart, command-line-interface, future

I'm the author of the Dart dshell package.

https://pub.dev/packages/dshell

Dshell is a library and tooling for writing dart cli scripts.

Dshell uses waitFor to hide futures from users as they serve little use in the typical cli application.

My problem is that if a future throws an unhandled exception whilst being handled by waitFor, it essentially shuts the application down.

I need to be able to capture any exception and then let the caller decided what to do with the exception.

Here is what I've tried so far. No of the catch techniques will capture the unhandled exception:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'dart:cli';

void main() {
  var future = throwException();
  try {
    future
        .catchError((Object e, StackTrace st) => print('onErrr: $e'))
        .whenComplete(() => print('future completed'));
    print(waitFor<int>(future));
  } // on AsyncError
  catch (e) {
    if (e.error is Exception) {
      print(e.error);
    } else if (e is AsyncError) {
      print('Rethrowing a non DShellException ${e}');
      rethrow;
    } else {
      print('Rethrowing a non DShellException ${e}');
      rethrow;
    }
  } finally {
    print('waitForEx finally');
  }
}

Future<int> throwException() {
  var complete = Completer<int>();

  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => throw Exception());
  return complete.future;
}
```

The dart waitFor has a line that makes me think this may not be possible:

> If the Future completes normally, its result is returned. If the Future completes with an error, the error and stack trace are wrapped in an AsyncError and thrown. If a microtask or message handler run during this call results in an unhandled exception, that exception will be propagated as though the microtask or message handler was the only Dart invocation on the stack. That is, unhandled exceptions in a microtask or message handler will skip over stacks suspended in a call to waitFor.

So I'm a little confused by the difference between a 'Future completes with an error' and 'a microtask ... results in an unhandled exception'.

Answer (score 3):

The `Future` returned by your `throwException` will never complete with either a value or an error. The error thrown by the `Future.delayed` is an unhandled async error, it is unrelated entirely to the `Future` that is returned from that method. The ways to get a Future that completes with an error are:

- The `Future.error` constructor.
- Using `Completer.completeError` on a not yet completed `Completer`.
- Using `throw` in an `async` method.
- Using `throw` in a callback passed to a `Future` constructor, or `.then`.

So in your example, the `Future.delayed` creates a `Future` that will complete with an error because of the `throw` in the callback. Nothing is listening on this Future. There is no `await`, no `.then` or `.catchError` chained off of it. Once a Future completes with an error, and it has no handlers for that error, it will bubble up to the surrounding error zone. See https://dart.dev/articles/archive/zones#handling-asynchronous-errors

If you want to be able to react to unhandled errors you can use `runZoned` - getting the details right can be tricky. Note that it's possible to have multiple unhandled async errors resulting from running some bit of code, and that the completion of a Future does not necessarily mean that there aren't other unhandled async errors that can surface later.

Comment: OK, so I had to read that a couple of times to get my head around it. But now I see that the delayed future isn't actually nested hence the problem. I've just experimented with a future.catchError to catch the Future.delayed and then use the completer to rethrow the error. Is this enough or do I need the zone to maximize the chances of catching the error. Are zones expensive to start? I've posted a possible answer.

Comment: It depends on whether you control all the code that is running. If you control all the code it should be possible to ensure that any failure is surfaced through the `Future`. Using `async` and `await`, and the lint `unawaited_futures` help with getting that right. If you don't control all the code it is not possible to guarantee there are no uncaught async errors and using a zone is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

From Nate Bosch I've devised a possible answer:

I hadn't realised that you can add multiple onCatchError methods to a future.
In DShell I'm  passed the future so I had assumed I couldn't modify it.

So I added an onCatchError to the Future.delayed and then use the completer to pass the error back up the correct stack.

So this seems to work, I'm just uncertain if I need to actually implement a zone to cast my catch net a little further?

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'dart:cli';

void main() {
  var future = throwExceptionV3();
  try {
    future
        .catchError((Object e, StackTrace st) => print('onErrr: $e'))
        .whenComplete(() => print('future completed'));
    print(waitFor<int>(future));
  } // on AsyncError
  catch (e) {
    if (e.error is Exception) {
      print(e.error);
    } else if (e is AsyncError) {
      print('Rethrowing a non DShellException ${e}');
      rethrow;
    } else {
      print('Rethrowing a non DShellException ${e}');
      rethrow;
    }
  } finally {
    print('waitForEx finally');
  }
}

Future<int> throwExceptionV3() {
  var complete = Completer<int>();
  try
  {

    var future = Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => throw Exception());
    future.catchError((Object e) { 
       print('caught 1'); 
       complete.completeError('caught ') ;
     });
  }
  catch (e)
  {
    print ('e');

  }
  return complete.future;
}
```

Comment: In your example the `try/catch` isn't accomplishing much since none of the code there will throw synchronously. The easiest way to write something with that behavior is:

    Future<int> throwExeptionV3() async {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
      throw Exception();
    }